# How to disable a bootstrap button permanently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drupal

On this page

https://www.s1biose.com/produit/savon-artisanal-bio-la-cannelle

I want to disable the "Add to Cart" button. So I added the following code in a JS file of my theme :

```
(function ($) {

  $('.commerce-order-item-add-to-cart-form .btn').prop("disabled", true);

})(window.jQuery);
```

It works, but there is a problem.

When I change the variation of the product, the button activates. Why ?

I want him to be disabled.

In this screenshot, the button is disabled

[image]

In this screenshot, the button should remain disabled. But it does not work

[image]

Comment: well something enables it.... figure out what removes it or replaces it. Impossible to help you with the information provided.

Comment: Can you provide some more information please? Perhaps the rest of the JS code.

Comment: @IbrahimTareq the code js is complete, after the site works with drupal 8. You can test directly on the site page

Comment: @IbrahimTareq I inspect the page but I do not understand why it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the dropdown fires a network event. Your DOM is updated on the success of this event. **I suggest you trace the functions which are responsible for re-rendering this component within your template and make the appropriate changes.**

```
const disableBtn = () => 
    $('.commerce-order-item-add-to-cart-form .btn').prop("disabled", true);
$(document).ajaxSuccess(disableBtn);
```

*The above code snippet is a simple and very naive solution. It works, but I don't recommend you use it, but learn from it.* I.e. I would NEVER do this in production.

Without access to your source, I can't help you further.